# Query to Clustered Index Table Slow in While loop in SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, indexing, while-loop

I'm very much scratching my head on this one.

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that loops using a While loop. Performance is staggeringly slow. I isolated it to the query in the While loop below:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT
SET @cnt = 0

DECLARE @ID INT
SET @ID = 10001

WHILE (@cnt < 500)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @ID = ID
    FROM mytbl
    WHERE ID > @ID

    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
END
```

The table itself has tens of thousands of rows. I need to process all rows. However, in the example above, with merely 500 records as the max, the stored procedure takes over 2 minutes to complete!

The table has a primary key/clustered index on the ID column. There no other indexes in this table. I rebuilt the clustered index, as well, to see if that might help speed up execution time. It did not.

I'm very much puzzled why an indexed, normalized table with maybe 20,000 records total is taking this long to process in the while loop of a stored procedure.

Any ideas? Should I try to use a dynamic cursor, instead?

If I store all the records in a table variable and then loop through the table variable, would that provide a huge performance gain?

Any ideas on how to address this would be appreciated. I'm stumped as to why an indexed table would be this slow for a READ operation.

Comment: Table definitions, query plan.

Comment: is this table frequently updated by users? May be some process is blocking your read.

Comment: I will state the obvious here, this code is doing nothing. I imagine that you have some more processing on it of course. What I mean is, what it is supposed to do? You run that query 500 times getting only the first result of that query per turn. This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Maybe if you explain what it us supposed to do we may present a better solution.

Comment: If you actually have a unique clustered index on that column, it shouldn't take that long unless there's something else going on affecting the table OR you're unwittingly doing something else that slows it down (e.g. if you try to run that query while including the execution plan, it's gonna produce 500 execution plans...). In any case, you would be better suited reworking your query to fit your needs - you should NEVER use loops (or cursors) if you can avoid them, and you can here.

Comment: ZLK: You were right on the money. I was running with Actual Execution Plan. I didn't realize that running with Actual Execution Plan would slow it down to such a degree. As far as the slowness, this seems to be the answer. Thank you so much to all for your help.